# Application Crashes on submit on a new campaign

Tags: android, parse-platform, crash

I am using parse.com, and I created a campaign creator.
However, when submitting,it crashes. 
I have:

- A title
- A Description
- Visibility dropdown
- date picker
- Int textbox
- Another "Action" TextBox.
- Submit Button

CreateNewCampaign java file:

```
    package com.alibdeir.signupactivity;

    import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.DatePicker;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.parse.Parse;
    import com.parse.ParseObject;

    import java.util.Calendar;

    public class CreateNewCampaign extends AppCompatActivity {
        Spinner typeSpinner;
        Button  datePicker;
        EditText titleEditText,descriptionEditText,countEditText,actionEditText;
        TextView dateTextView;
        int day_x;
        int month_x;
        int year_x;
        static final int DIALOG_ID=0;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.create_new_campaign);
            Parse.initialize(this, "g***************8kJy8piZZD4JRab", "BzguaPll0zUC8lU5******************zFV");
            //region set spinner array+
            typeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.typeDropDown);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dropDownTypeAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.typeDropDown, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            dropDownTypeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            typeSpinner.setAdapter(dropDownTypeAdapter);
            //endregion
            titleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleEditText);
            descriptionEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descriptionEditText);
            countEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CountEditText);
            actionEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.actionEditText);
            datePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.expirationDateButton);
            dateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            day_x = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            month_x = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            year_x = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        }
        public void datePickerOnCLick(View v){
            showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
        }
        @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
            if(id==DIALOG_ID)
                return new DatePickerDialog(this,dpickerListener,year_x,month_x,day_x);
            return null;

        }
        private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpickerListener
                = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                year_x = year;
                month_x = monthOfYear;
                day_x = dayOfMonth;
                String dateString = day_x + "/" + month_x + "/" + year_x;
                dateTextView.setText(dateString);
            }
        };
        public void createNewCampaign(View v){

            //region editTextStrings
            String typeSpinnerResultString = typeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String titleResultString = titleEditText.getText().toString();
            String descriptionResultString = descriptionEditText.getText().toString();
            int countResultInt = Integer.parseInt(countEditText.getText().toString());
            String actionResultString = actionEditText.getText().toString();
            //endregion
            if(titleResultString.length()<6){
                Context titleLengthErrorContext = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence titleLengthErrorText = "Your title must be at least 6 characters";
                int titleLengthErrorDuration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast titleLengthError = Toast.makeText(titleLengthErrorContext,titleLengthErrorText,titleLengthErrorDuration);
                titleLengthError.show();
            }
            if(titleResultString.isEmpty()){
                Context titleLengthErrorContext = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence titleLengthErrorText = "Your title must be at least 6 characters";
                int titleLengthErrorDuration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast titleLengthError = Toast.makeText(titleLengthErrorContext,titleLengthErrorText,titleLengthErrorDuration);
                titleLengthError.show();
            }
            if(descriptionResultString.length()<15){
                Context descriptionLengthErrorContext = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence descriptionLengthErrorText = "Your description must be at least 15 characters";
                int descriptionLengthErrorDuration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast descriptionLengthError = Toast.makeText(descriptionLengthErrorContext,descriptionLengthErrorText,descriptionLengthErrorDuration);
                descriptionLengthError.show();
            }
            if(descriptionResultString.isEmpty()){
                Context descriptionLengthErrorContext = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence descriptionLengthErrorText = "Your description must be at least 15 characters";
                int descriptionLengthErrorDuration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast descriptionLengthError = Toast.makeText(descriptionLengthErrorContext,descriptionLengthErrorText,descriptionLengthErrorDuration);
                descriptionLengthError.show();
            }
            if(countResultInt==0){
                Context countSizeErrorContext = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence countSizeErrorText = "Your count must be greater than 0";
                int countSizeErrorDuration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast countSizeError = Toast.makeText(countSizeErrorContext,countSizeErrorText,countSizeErrorDuration);
                countSizeError.show();

            }
            if(actionResultString.length()<4){
                Context actionLengthErrorContext = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence actionLengthErrorText = "Your action must contain 4 characters";
                int actionLengthErrorDuration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast actionLengthError = Toast.makeText(actionLengthErrorContext,actionLengthErrorText,actionLengthErrorDuration);
                actionLengthError.show();
            }
            if(titleResultString.length()>15){
                Context titleLengthErrorContext = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence titleLengthErrorText = "Your title must be less than 15 characters";
                int titleLengthErrorDuration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast titleLengthError = Toast.makeText(titleLengthErrorContext,titleLengthErrorText,titleLengthErrorDuration);
                titleLengthError.show();

            }
            if(descriptionResultString.length()>512){
                Context descriptionLengthErrorContext = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence descriptionLengthErrorText = "Your description must be less that 512 characters";
                int descriptionLengthErrorDuration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast descriptionLengthError = Toast.makeText(descriptionLengthErrorContext,descriptionLengthErrorText,descriptionLengthErrorDuration);
                descriptionLengthError.show();
            }

            if(typeSpinnerResultString=="Select an Item"){
                Context SpinnerErrorContext = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence SpinnerLengthErrorText = "Please select an item";
                int SpinnerLengthErrorDuration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast SpinnerLengthError = Toast.makeText(SpinnerErrorContext,SpinnerLengthErrorText,SpinnerLengthErrorDuration);
                SpinnerLengthError.show();
            }
            if(dateTextView.getText()=="dd/mm/yy"){
                Context DateErrorContext = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence DateErrorText = "Please select an item";
                int DateErrorDuration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast DateError = Toast.makeText(DateErrorContext,DateErrorText,DateErrorDuration);
                DateError.show();
            }

           else {
                ParseObject listViewCreation = new ParseObject("Campaign");
                listViewCreation.put("Title",titleResultString);
                listViewCreation.put("Description",descriptionResultString);
                listViewCreation.put("Count",countResultInt);
                listViewCreation.put("Action",actionResultString);
                listViewCreation.put("Visibility",typeSpinnerResultString);
                listViewCreation.put("Expiration_Date",dateTextView);
            }
        }


    }
```

create_new_campaign

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/titleEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="@string/titleHint"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/titleTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/PictureText"
        android:id="@+id/pictureTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/titleText"
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/titleEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="93.333dp"
        android:layout_height="93.333dp"
        android:id="@+id/pictureImageView"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleEditText"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/pictureTextView"
        android:contentDescription="picture for the occasion" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/descriptionText"
        android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pictureImageView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/descriptionEditText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/descriptionTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/titleEditText"
        android:hint="@string/descriptionHint" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/ExpirationDateText"
        android:id="@+id/expirationDateTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/descriptionEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose Date"
        android:id="@+id/expirationDateButton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/expirationDateTextView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/expirationDateTextView"
        android:onClick="datePickerOnCLick" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/visibilityText"
        android:id="@+id/visibilityTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/expirationDateButton"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/typeDropDown"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/visibilityTextView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/visibilityTextView"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/countText"
        android:id="@+id/CountTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/typeDropDown"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/CountEditText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/typeDropDown"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/CountTextView"
        android:hint="@string/countHint" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/Action"
        android:id="@+id/actionTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/typeDropDown"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/actionEditText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/typeDropDown"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/actionTextView"
        android:hint="@string/actionHint" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/submitButton"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="createNewCampaign" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="day/month/year"
        android:id="@+id/dateTextView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_above="@+id/typeDropDown"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/expirationDateButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.alibdeir.signupactivity, PID: 16161
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:278)
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19270)
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:273)
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19270) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.alibdeir.signupactivity.CreateNewCampaign.createNewCampaign(CreateNewCampaign.java:81)
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:273) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19270) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
11-13 18:27:54.216 16161-16161/com.alibdeir.signupactivity E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Pardon me if this has been asked before, but I've searched about the cause in logct and I found nothing. If it is a duplicate, please tell me instead of marking it**

Comment: You're trying to parse an empty string as a number at `com.alibdeir.signupactivity.CreateNewCampaign.createNewCampaign(CreateNewCampaign.java:81)`.

Comment: nevermind, I solved it myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like I ended up solving it myself. Since this is old I forgot what was the problem, however it was solved.
Thanks